# Problem "atime in future"

Tags: ubuntu, atime

I have a problem running Aide. After doing different tasks in the system, most notarius ones were to change user and home name and to change system's date to EST.
Then I run Aide and it showed a huge list of files with flag:
`atime in future`

```
aide# ./bin/aide --config=./aide.conf --init
/bin/sh atime in future
/etc/os-release atime in future
/etc/localtime atime in future
/etc/alternatives/python3 atime in future
/etc/alternatives/lzma atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini atime in future
/etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini atime in future
.
.
.
```

If for example we `stat` on the first one..

```
# stat -c %x /bin/sh
2020-06-21 17:44:34.996267989 -0500
```

that are several days in future..

```
# date
Mon 15 Jun 2020 06:13:28 PM EST
```

Trying to touch the file has no effect, I don't know if this has relation with the issue:

```
# date +%s
1592262916
# touch -a 1592262916 /bin/sh
# stat -c %X /bin/sh
1592779474
# touch /bin/sh
# stat -c %x /bin/sh
2020-06-21 17:44:34.996267989 -0500
```

any idea about how to solve this?

Ubuntu 18.04
4.9.140-tegra
Nvida Jetson Nano board

Comment: still stacked at this...

Comment: I'm probably overcomplicating things, but what is the output of `hwclock`?

Comment: I think it was the correct date. I want to remember that I checked it. Now I returned to a previous backup image for not loosing more time, but I would like to debug this issue to understand why happened...